# How to fix "Error: spawn c:\Python\27\python.exe ENOENT"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules, package.json

I'm setting up a deployment folder to execute a number of grunt tools. When I use 'npm install' I'm coming across a number of errors.

[image: npm run]

These errors seem to be signalling a 'node-sass' issue but I'm not convinced. It's important to note that I have the 2.7 version of Python installed, installed the latest version of sass, chosen my npm path as 2.7 in the C drive and rebuilt the npm.

[image: package file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `node-sass` compiler.

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you, will it affect anything in particular?

Comment: Your build needs `node-sass` compiler which wasn't present. You couldn't have built your project. It will not affect any of your code. @himynameis

Comment: Thanks for the help.